# How I can read styles in ul tag using loop

Tags: javascript

Is there any way to read background-color and color in styles and put it in list using javascript specifically loop ?

*HTML*

```
<ul id="list">
                <li>
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="test1" style="background-color: #fff333;"></div>
                        <p class="test2" style="color: #000;">#ef5777</p>
                    </div>
                </li>
</ul>
```

*JavaScript*

```
<script>
                var background = [];
                var colors = []; 
                // is there any way to put background and color in one array without 2 array ?
                // after that what should I do ?

</script>
```

Comment: Yes, there are multiple ways to do this. Please [edit] your question and include _your_ attempts.

Comment: I created arraylist already but after that idk what I do

Comment: @Xufox I updated it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your just wanting to retrieve what's in the style attribute, then you can just use `getAttribute("style")` on the DOM node.

If your wanting the physical color, that also takes into account CSS, there is getComputedStyle too,.

Here is an example of the getAttribute way.

```js
const items = document.querySelectorAll('#list *');

const styles = [];

for (const item of items) {
  const st = item.getAttribute("style");
  if (st) styles.push(st);
}

console.log(styles);
```

```html
<ul id="list">
  <li>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="test1" style="background-color: #fff333;">xx</div>
      <p class="test2" style="color: #000;">#ef5777</p>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

And here is an example of using getComputedStyle

```js
const items = document.querySelectorAll('#list *');

const colors = [];
const background = [];

for (const item of items) {
  const c = window.getComputedStyle(item);
  colors.push(c.getPropertyValue('color'));
  background.push(c.getPropertyValue('background-color'));
}

console.log(colors);
console.log(background);
```

```html
<ul id="list">
  <li>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="test1" style="background-color: #fff333;">xx</div>
      <p class="test2" style="color: #000;">#ef5777</p>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: It's working thanks but what's difference between const or var in javascript ?

Comment: In the above examples you could use `var` without problems, but `const` & `let` are what most modern browsers have, and it's better to use these due to how `var` is functionally scoped, rather than block scoped.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const

Comment: It's just an array, you can use `for loops`  `for of`  `Array.forEach` etc.    Some useful information on MDN -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Looping_code

Comment: Then I can't read any item after put it in list for example #fff333 output ?

Comment: do you can put example please